# How to store the Public link in a variable for a backup (using pgbackup:url) on heroku using the heroku-api.rb file

Tags: ruby, api, heroku, add-on

I have an app on Heroku that I'd like to backup my production database on Heroku to a backup file repository on a separate cloud service providers site.  To do this, I need to get the public URL from heroku for the backup, I'm just not sure how to call the api to get this.  Here's some rough sudo code of how I'd like to get this, but obviously the syntax is coming out of my head/other peoples examples so it's not working code.

> require 'heroku-api'
>
> heroku = Heroku::API.new(:api_key => API_KEY)
>
> *> (if the backup file is too large, then your database is split into
>   multiple backup files so I need to loop through each of the public
>   URL's generated)*
>
> heroku.get_addons('my-heroku-app').pgbackup.url.each do |public_file|
>
> current_url = public_file.url.link
>   *(here is where I would use that link to copy the file to another server)*
>
> end

Heroku provides documentation on how to do this from a commandline, not the api.  Here's a snippet from their website on how to do this from the command line.

```
> Downloading a backup
> 
> You can create a publicly accessible backup URL with the pgbackups:url
> command. This is useful when migrating data between applications,
> upgrading starter tier plans, and exporting your data.
> 
> $ heroku pgbackups:url
> "http://s3.amazonaws.com/hkpgbackups/app1234567@heroku.com/b004.dump?AWSAccessKeyId=ABCD1234&Expires=1289261668&Signature=3mMBeKISewgEUDT%2FL5mRz4EYS4M%3D"
> By default the URL will reference the most recent backup. To access
> another backup pass the backup ID to the pgbackups:url command.
```

In addition, they have a little help in the documentation on github https://github.com/heroku/heroku.rb but the samples on that site don't go far enough for me to understand how to actually work with this add-on.

Any help with this would be MUCH appreciated!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a separate addon, it has it's own api, and is not a part of heroku-rb. If you want to see what API calls the CLI makes check out this file: https://github.com/heroku/heroku/blob/master/lib/heroku/client/pgbackups.rb

However please note that while you can figure out the api it is **not** documented and can and will change without notice. This is not out of malice, rather we haven't yet spent the time to nail down a solid api for pgbackups, one that we'd feel proud of standing behind.

In the meantime, go ahead and use that though, just keep an eye on it.